# How to find a specific 'string' and print out the whole line?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have a file named `myfile.csv` containing the following:

```
 abc:123:myname:1231
 def:423324:arbitrary:value:string
 StackExchange:Unix:Linux
```

From the terminal I run `./myscript.sh def`

The contents of `myscript.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
key_word_I_am_looking_for=$1
my_variable=`cat myfile.csv | awk -F: -v keyword="$key_word_I_am_looking_for" '( $1 == keyword )' END{print "$@" }'`
echo "$my_variable"
```

I want the code to search for the word `def` or any other word in the first parameter in the `myfile.csv` ie `abc` or `StackExchange`. Once found I would like it to take the whole line out without the seperators and place it in the `my_variable` variable, and echo it out to the terminal (so the output would look like: `def 423324 arbitrary value string` when `./myscript.sh def` is entered to the terminal. When `./myscript.sh StackExchange` the output would be `StackExchange Unix Linux` ).

Where am I going wrong? Is there an alternative?

Comment: `grep 'def' myfile.csv | tr ':' ' '`

Comment: `while IFS=':' read -r first a b c d e ; do [ "$first" = "$key_word_I_am_looking_for" ] && echo "$first $a $b $c $d $e" ; done < myfile.csv`

Comment: I like the 2nd, but instead of guessing how many fields there are, use `read -a` to use an array.

Comment: @glennjackman Well, it is good idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your awk syntax is a little wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F: -v keyword="$1" '$1 == keyword {$1=$1; print}' myfile.csv
```

The trick here is reassigning the value of one of the fields forces awk to recalculate $0 using the output file separator. Here, the default OFS is a space, so assigning the value of $1 to itself changes the colons to spaces.

A non-awk way to write this is:

```
grep "^$1:" myfile.csv | tr ":" " "
```

but that uses regular expression matching, not string equality

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `sed` alternative:

```
sed -n '/^def:/s/:/ /gp' myfile.csv
```

If you pass the string as first positional parameter:

```
sed -n "/^$1:/s/:/ /gp" myfile.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Through python.

```
$ python -c "import sys;
with open(sys.argv[2]) as f:
    for line in f:
        if sys.argv[1] == line.split(':')[0]:
            print ' '.join(line.strip().split(':'))" def file
def 423324 arbitrary value string
```

Just run the above script on  terminal with the search keyword as firs argument and the file-name as second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using grep:

`grep ^abc file | awk -F ":" '{print $1" " $2" "  $3" "  $4}'`

Comment: I would’ve added more anchoring to the grep, such as a trailing colon. Also, the OP asked for the result to be in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne '.put if .=split(":")[0] eq "def";' myfile.csv
```

OUTPUT:

```
def 423324 arbitrary value string
```

Language notes: Perl-family languages utilize the concept of a 'topic'-variable. Raku extends and regularizes this concept (see Rosetta Code link below). Because routines now default to the `$_` topic variable, a leading period is all that's needed to indicate action *on* the `$_` topic variable. Writing out the above code 'longhand' you'd actually get:

```
raku -ne '$_.put if $_.=split(":")[0] eq "def";'
```

Finally, Raku offers a `.=` *binary assignment* operator, wherein essentially an interposed `=` (equal sign) is all that's needed to update the lvalue. Thus the code `my $temp = $_.fn(…); $_ = $temp;` can be compacted to `$_.=fn(…)`  . Shorter...and no need to create a `$temp` temporary variable!

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Topic_variable#Raku
https://docs.raku.org/routine/.=
https://raku.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
awk -v input="$input" '$0 ~ input {gsub(":"," ",$0);print }' filename
```

example

```
 sh script.sh abc
abc 123 myname 1231
```